# Runtime Error : Cannot read property 'title' of undefined (Ionic 3)

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, runtime-error, ionic3

Everything seems good but i got an error like that for detailpage.Please help me.I am about to go crazy.

detail.ts file :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Note } from '../../model/note/note.model';
import { NoteListService } from '../../services/note-list.service';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-detail',
  templateUrl: 'detail.html',
})
export class DetailPage {

note : Note = {
    title: '',
    content: ''
  };

  constructor( private noteListService: NoteListService,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private fdb:AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad DetailPage');
    this.note = this.navParams.get('note');
  }
}
```

detail.html file :

```
 <ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="ecoblue">
    <ion-title>{{note.title}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  {{note.content}}

</ion-content>
```

So when I load the page, there is an runtime error in console saying "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined".
I'm waiting for your solutions.

Comment: Did you verify that your `this.navParams.get('note')` call is returning something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you can write a `?` after `note` in your view, like this:

```
  <ion-navbar color="ecoblue">
    <ion-title>{{note?.title}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
```

That will make disappear your error, but for a better solution you should check that you're receiving the correct data in the navParams.